# Highlight the Axis OX and OY in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I need help to highlight the Axis OX and OY in matplotlib.pyplot. Im using it to render function graphs and without highlited OX and OY graphs look unfinished.
Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def render_func_graph(formula, x_range):
    try:
        fig = plt.figure()    
        x = np.array(x_range)
        y = eval(formula)
        print(y)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'go-')
        plt.scatter(0,0)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))  

def main():
    func = input('f(x):')
    render_func_graph(func, range(-10, 10))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And i'm getting this for `1/x` formula

[image: Result]

And i want to get something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kR0ax.png)

Comment: Can you better describe your expected result?

Comment: Added link to the expected result

Comment: Can you please tell in how far [this example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/spine_placement_demo.html) does not help? In addition to a picure, also describe what you want and what prevents you from getting there. Since SO is not a code-writing service, chances are higher to get an answer if you show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Oh, your example is what i need. I was looking in the wrong direction. I tryed to render lines in OX and OY axis and looped on it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the finished code looks like the below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def render_func_graph(formula, x_range):
    try:
        fig = plt.figure()    
        x = np.array(x_range)
        y = eval(formula)
        plt.xticks(np.arange(min(x), max(x)+1, 1.0))
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        plt.plot(x, y, 'go-')
        ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
        ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
        ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
        ax.spines['left'].set_smart_bounds(True)
        ax.spines['bottom'].set_smart_bounds(True)
        ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
        ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')
        plt.scatter(0,0)
        plt.grid(True)
        plt.show()
    except Exception as err:
        print(str(err))  

def main():
    func = input('f(x):')
    render_func_graph(func, np.arange(-5, 5, 0.5))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the result for `1/x` is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHFmv.png)

Comment: Please highlight the specific function that solves the problem and document why. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.axvspan), it looks like you could use

---

```
#matplotlib.pyplot.axes(*args, **kwargs) -> could just modify axis color

#matplotlib.pyplot.axhline(y=0, xmin=0, xmax=1, hold=None, **kwargs)
axhline(linewidth=4, color='r') #adds thick red line @ y=0

#matplotlib.pyplot.axvline(x=0, ymin=0, ymax=1, hold=None, **kwargs)
axvline(linewidth=4, color='r') #adds thick red line @ x=0
```